# jsp:useBean duplicate id checking

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7

In my jsp page i have following code snippet. This page is coming recursive way during my flow. I am getting a duplicate bean id error while execution of the jsp in the middle of the flow. Can you anyone help me how to check whether bean id already exist or not for the following code?

The full code has been given

```
    code.jsp

<%@ page language="java" %>   
<%@ page import="com.ubsw.risk.AUT_Authenticator.*" %>

<%
   String path= System.getProperty("dev_property_path");   
   System.out.println("dev_property_path----->"+path); 
%>
<jsp:useBean id="orbinfra" scope="session" class="com.ubsw.risk.Creation.web.OrbinfraBean" >
<jsp:setProperty name="orbinfra" property="propertiesFile" value="<%=path%>"/>
<%
    System.out.println("B4 init of Orbinfra");
    try {
        orbinfra.init();
            System.out.println("after init of Orbinfra");
    } catch( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println("error in Orbinfra"+ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
%>
    <html>
        Caught exception while creating orbinfra <%= ex %>
    </html>
<%
    }
%>
</jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="security" scope="session" class="com.ubsw.risk.Creation.web.AuthenticatorBean" >
</jsp:useBean> 

<%
    boolean showLogin;
    showLogin = true;
    boolean additionalMessage = false;
    String message = "Warning - Users login has expired";
    boolean hasAdminRights = false;
    // is there a command being sent
    String checkcommand = request.getParameter("command");

    // does user want to login
    if( checkcommand != null ) {
        if( checkcommand.equals("login") ) {
            try {
                    String authenticatorModuleLookupValue= System.getProperty("authenticatorModuleLookupValue");
                    String cookieNamevalue= System.getProperty("cookieNamevalue");
                    System.out.println(request.getParameter("User_Name"));              
                    System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());                
                    System.out.println(request.getLocalAddr()); 
                    System.out.println("hello P"); 
                //HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(true);
                 System.out.println(authenticatorModuleLookupValue+":"+cookieNamevalue);
                                security.setloginInfo(authenticatorModuleLookupValue,cookieNamevalue);
                security.logon(request.getParameter("User_Name"), request.getParameter("Password"), request.getRemoteAddr(), response );            
                System.out.println("what happened?");System.out.println(security);
                showLogin = false;
            } catch( LogonFailure le ) {
                additionalMessage = true;
                message = "Logon failed : " + le.reason;
            } catch( Exception ex ) {
                additionalMessage = true;
                message = "Failed, caught an exception : " + ex;
            }
        }
    }

    if( showLogin ) {   
        try {
            showLogin = !security.hasPermission( request );
            if( ! showLogin ) {
                hasAdminRights = security.hasAdminPermission( request );
            }
        } catch( TicketIsExpired te ) {
            additionalMessage = true;
            message = "Warning - Users login has expired";
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            additionalMessage = true;
            message = "Exception - " + ex;
        }
    } 
//System.out.println("showLogin"+showLogin);
    // do we need to show login or not
    if( showLogin ) {
    %>

    <html>
    <body>
    <FORM NAME="loginForm" ACTION="index.jsp" METHOD="post">
    <center>
    <%
            if( additionalMessage ) {
    %>
                <b> <%= message %> </b><br>
    <%
            }
            //System.out.println("showLogin"+showLogin);
    %>


    <br>
    <br>
    <center>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="2" bordercolor="#60A0A0">
        <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='command' VALUE='login'>
        <body>


                    <tr bgcolor="#60A0A0">
                                    <td align="left" height="17"><font face="Verdana" color="white"><span
                                        style="color: white; font-weight: bold; font-variant: normal; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left">
                                        <center>
                                        Creation Web Application
                                        </center>
                                        </span></font></td>
        </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#60A0A0">
                <td align="left" height="17"><font face="Verdana" color="white"><span
                    style="color: white; font-weight: bold; font-variant: normal; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left">Please 
                Login</span></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" height="166">
                <table border="0" height="116" width="460">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="16" width="70"></td>
                            <td height="16" width="87"></td>
                            <td height="16" width="164"></td>
                            <td height="16" width="136"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="25" width="70"></td>
                            <td height="25" width="87"><span
                                style="color: black; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; text-align: center">Username:</span></td>
                            <td height="25" width="164"><input type="text"
                                name="User_Name" maxlength="20"
                                style="height: 25px; font-family: Verdana; width: 153px"></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="1" width="70"></td>
                            <td height="1" width="87"></td>
                            <td height="1" width="164"></td>
                            <td height="1" width="136"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="25" width="70"></td>
                            <td height="25" width="87"><span
                                style="color: black; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; text-align: center">Password:</span></td>
                            <td height="25" width="164"><input type="password"
                                name="Password"
                                style="height: 25px; font-family: Verdana; width: 153px"
                                maxlength="25"></td>
                            <td height="25" width="136"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="19" width="70"></td>
                            <td height="19" width="87"></td>
                            <td height="19" width="164"></td>
                            <td height="19" width="136"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="27" width="70"></td>
                            <td height="27" width="100"></td>
                            <td height="27" width="136">
                            <center><input type="submit" name="Login"
                                value="Login"
                                style="height: 25px; bottom: auto; right: auto; font-family: Verdana; background-color: #60A0A0; width: 62px; top: auto; left: auto"></center></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="1" width="70"></td>
                            <td height="1" width="87"></td>
                            <td height="1" width="164"></td>
                            <td height="1" width="136"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </center>
    </FORM>
    </body>
</html>

    <%
            return;
        }
    %>
```

Comment: did you include any other jsp, @nayan ?

Comment: No there are no include .. here is the code                          <%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import="com.ubsw.risk.AUT_Authenticator.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.Cookie" %>
<%@ page import="com.ubsw.risk.Creation.web.OrbinfraBean" %>

<%String path= System.getProperty("dev_property_path");
System.out.println("dev_property_path----->"+path); %>

Comment: No luck still receiving :-    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/adminOptions/../jspIncludes/check.jsp (line: 9, column: 0) useBean: Duplicate bean name: {0}

Comment: Can you make a search in the project using ide for the content: `<jsp:useBean id="orbinfra"`, @nayan

Comment: Why are using Scriplet whereas you achieve it using JSTL & EL as well?

Comment: You say `This page is coming recursive way during my flow`. Does the error occurs at all time including first ? And how is the page called from client browser (directly or via a servlet) ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying `This page is coming recursive way during my flow.`

Try changing `scope="page"` to `scope="request"`

Or try renaming beanId to `"orbinfra1"`

```
<jsp:useBean id="orbinfra1" scope="session" class="com.ubsw.risk.Creation.web.OrbinfraBean" >    
    <jsp:setProperty name="orbinfra1" property="propertiesFile" value="<%=path%>"/>
</jsp:useBean>
```

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/adminOptions/../jspIncludes/check.jsp (line: 9, column: 0) useBean: Duplicate bean name: {0}

Comment: Ok.then check if same bean name is used somewhere in the page.

Comment: No it is not used anywhere. It will be good if you can suggest me some  code where i can check whether the bean id exist or not.

Comment: One more check..have you commented same line.. using HTML script before like <!-- -->

Comment: which line you want to mean? please suggest

Comment: This line - <jsp:useBean id="orbinfra" scope="page" class="com.ubsw.risk.Creation.web.OrbinfraBean" >

Comment: No .. no comments in that line.

Comment: Leaner I have updated the code in the question. Remember this page is key page for several flow. This page has been included 2-3 times within the flow.

Comment: Why do you need `orbinfra.init();` in try-catch, try removing that

Comment: I have tried to make it without try-catch . still issue persists